# where to find sbt generate scala case class for protobuf?

Tags: scala, protocol-buffers

I was following the scalaPB examples https://github.com/scalapb/ScalaPB
After I downloaded the examples code and run sbt compile, I am expecting a scala case class code to be generated in the source. However, I don't see that under src.
Could anyone got it work shed some lights, where is the file generated?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are temporary files so they are in the `target` tree in the `scala-2.13` directory.